# Why is ToLowerCase() giving a type error in Express js / Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

req.body.email.ToLowerCase() gives an error in Expressjs. Do we need to require something to use it?

Comment: I don't understand why so many questions just say there is "an error". There is not just an error. There is an error *message*. You should always provide the exact error message. Otherwise any answer is just a lucky guess and you waste the time of people.

Comment: @str Sorry, just my first question. Won't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email from the body is a string you can use the method `toLowerCase();`. You have a capital letter at the beginning.